# Call do_action class's function

Tags: actions

There is the following do_action

```
else
do_action( 'example', $this->nothing());
```

Where nothing() does exactly what it sounds like.

This logic is in a public function testFunction in a class called Test.

What I would like to do is hook into this function (I'm in a different plugin), and call a different function (looppages()) that is already in the same class as the above logic like this:

```
add_action( 'example', Test::looppages);
```

Can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't.

`add_action( 'hook', array( [class], "method_name" ) );` is the right way to use a method as callback. Read about [how to use methods as callback](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action#Using_add_action_with_a_class) in the codex.

If you want to use a static method as callback, do it in this way:

`add_action( 'hook', array( "ClassName", "method_name" ) );`

Comment: I'm calling from one __construct to another though, so in my do_action do I need to pass this as a parameter or something?

Comment: Any idea as to above question?

Comment: Code examples are very helpfull. And if you post more than just one or two lines of code, others get a chance to understand what you are planning.

Comment: @Ralf912 Any Idea how will affect it if the function is private?

Comment: it works thanks for this post @Ralf912